# When entering into XML files, Android Studio closes

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new in Android. When i entering into XML files, Android Studio closes. It does not give me an error or anything else, just closes. And when i go to **Help -> Check for update...**, give me:

> You already have the latest version of Android Studio installed.   To
>   configure automatic update settings, see the **Updates** dialog of
>   your IDE Settings.

And in my Updates Settings, channel set to `stable channel`.

**Note:**
Current Android Studio version: `Android Studio 1.0.2`
Build number: `Al-135.1653844`

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

This could be related to the heap size allocated to android studio, OR CPU usage in your system is high,

Try increasing the heap size by going here

**android-studio\bin**
and change  **-Xmx** and **-Xms** values in **studio.exe.vmoptions** or **studio64.exe.vmoptions**

Comment: My system is x86, so i change `studio.exe.vmoptions`. and when i reopen AS give me this error: Error launching AS. Faileld to create JVM.JVM Path: c:\Program files\java\jdk1.7.0_21\jre.if you already have 32-bit jdk installed, define a java_home variable in computer....

Comment: In that case, try changing Only MaxPermSize=256m to some higher value
and do not change -Xmx and -Xms

Comment: again, give me same error. is because jdk 32-bit not running in x86. and x64 running?

Comment: If your machine is X86 and jdk is 32 bit, then that should be fine.